# How do I clear sectors Ochre and Opal in Space Station Oblivion/Driller?

Tags: driller

I played this game way too much when I was little. I remember eventually getting a strategy guide. Dusted the game off again, and I could remember most of it, but sectors Opal and Ochre are giving me fits. I thought there was a weak point in the force field, but I can't find it. And I have no idea where to drill in Opal at all; random drilling is getting me nowhere, and the sign tells me nothing useful.

Comment: If it helps, I found a game manual: http://gamesdbase.com/Media/SYSTEM/Atari_ST/manual/Formated/Space_Station_Oblivion_-_1988_-_Incentive_Software.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (finally, after lots of searching) found a solution for this game for the c64, I was totally stuck replaying it on my cpc464.

http://tin.at/c64/_single_files/drillersolution.sol.txt

The forcefield has two switches, one in graphite needs to be driven into and one in an overhead structure in malachite needs to be shot with the recon craft.

The sign in opal is the Y co-ord, I think the sign itself is on the X co-ord.

Hope this helps.